# expand all div height when content of one div increase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have below code which iterate set of objects and fill the details of it to a anchor tag inside a div. Some details can be contain long description. I want to expand the height of all anchor tags.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 offer-item-button" ng-repeat="offer in activeOffers">
    <a href="#/products"  class="thumbnail" ng-click="onLocalOfferClick(offer,store)">
        <h5 class="text-right">#{{offer.SlotId}}</h5>
        <h4 class="text-bold">{{offer.ProductName}}</h4>
        <h5 class="text-bold">$ {{offer.ProductPrice | number:2}}</h5>
        <h6 >{{offer.Description}}</h6>
    </a>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/mpekatus/)

If any item has a long description it need to increase its height to fit the entire content. also other divs need to get the same height

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use `display:flex;`. For reference [click here](https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard)

Comment: can its possible for you to create a working code snippet for this?

Comment: @Mani that's a good reference. but **display:flex;** sets all elements inside that div to float left

Answer (score 0):

you could use on your a tag.

```
height:100%;
```

`box-sizing:border-box;`

Answer (score 0):

for div add css property:

> width:500px;(width of your choice)

And for every element in anchor tag add css property:

> width:100%;word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: I want to increase the height and it should be dynamic to the content.